# pulseUi (Pulse Secure on Ubuntu)

Tags: software-installation

I can't get pulseUi (Pulse Secure) to work, although it's supposed to be supported for Ubuntu 14.04 LTS. I have installed version 5.3R2, build number 422 of pulseUi

`/usr/local/pulse> pulseUi
pulseUi: error while loading shared libraries: libwebkitgtk-1.0.so.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
/usr/local/pulse> echo $LD_LIBRARY_PATH
.:/usr/local/pulse:/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu`

Following a suggestion on some forum, I tried

`> sudo apt-get install libwebkitgtk-1.0-0:i386
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 libwebkitgtk-1.0-0:i386 : Depends: libenchant1c2a:i386 (>= 1.6.0) but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
> apt-mark showhold
>`

Comment: Could you please link to the "some forum" you are referring to?

Comment: After upgrading to 16.04LTS I was able to get PulseUi to work.  In retrospective, my problem might have had little to do with PulseUi per-se, but with some sort of conflict between i386 and i686 in my installation.
It's been too long for me to remember where exactly I read that forum hint, but it was probably based on the search term `error while loading shared libraries: libwebkitgtk-1.0.so.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory`, without reference to Pulse Secure.

Answer (score 1):

Try installing the correct version of WebKit library:

For 64 bit:

```
sudo apt-get install libwebkitgtk-1.0-0
```

For 32-bit:

```
sudo apt-get install libwebkitgtk-1.0-0:i386
```

Try running pulseUI once again:

```
/usr/local/pulse/pulseUi
```

Comment: Thanks! That problem existed for Ubuntu 14.04 LTS. It works for 16.04 LTS and 18.04 LTS.